# list of commas after not

Tags: punctuation

I am confused by the meaning of the following sentence:

> This is only valid when the reservation status is not cancelled, departed,
>   in-house.

what's the scope of the not in this sentence? Just "not cancelled", or also includes "not departed" and "not in-house"?

Comment: If you have to ask here, the source didn't explain it well. It's not as if a definitive answer on this side would corroborate or deny authoritatively the source's intention anyway.

Comment: A problem is that a 'departed reservation' on its own takes some understanding.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth changed to `reservation status`

Comment: Can you add a bit more context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would take it to mean

Not any of {cancelled, departed, in-house}.

However, the sentence needs an OR to clarify that all three items are a list that "not" distributes over.

...not cancelled, departed, or in-house.

Or, if you prefer, [neither....nor]: 
...neither cancelled, nor departed, nor in-house

Alternatively (or in addition) it would help if the statuses were identified by capitalization or quote marks:

not Cancelled, Departed, or In-House

not "cancelled", "departed", or "in-house"

(These avert the misreading of "not cancelled" as a status.)